# iPhone - implicit declarations error

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am using OpenGL lines like

```
glPushMatrix();
```

on my iPhone app and receiving this error:

implicit declaration of function glPushMatrix is invalid in C99.

How do I make Xcode stop whining?

thanks.

Comment: This is not "whining". When the compiler "whines", it's because you're doing something wrong. It may not be something that stops your code from compiling, but it's something that can come around and bite you in the backside at some point. The compiler is trying to keep that from happening. Stop complaining about the messages and pay attention to them. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is thinking that the `glPushMatrix()` command is a function you created. Have you `#import`-ed the `OpenGL` framework. If you have, then it probably isn't linked.

Answer (score 2):

For glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() you should use OpenGLES/ES1 folder, not ES2 or ES3:

```
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/glext.h>
```